# How to use ChipGroup in Android

Tags: android

In my application I have **BottomSheetDialogFragment** and into this `fragment` I have `ChipGroup`. 
I want dynamically checked **chip** of this `ChipGroup`. 
I write below code, when first time open this dialog, everything is okey and show checked chip. 
But when close dialog and open again dialog crashed application and show null error!
**My fragment codes:**

```
class MenuFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    //Binding
    private var _binding: FragmentMenuBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        _binding = FragmentMenuBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //InitView
        binding.apply {
            setupChip(fillChipData(), mealChipGroup)
            mealChipGroup.findViewById<Chip>(3).isChecked = true

    }

    private fun fillChipData(): MutableList<String> {
        return mutableListOf(
            "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"
        )
    }

    private fun setupChip(list: MutableList<String>, view: ChipGroup) {
        list.forEach {
            val chip = Chip(requireContext())
            chip.text = it
            view.addView(chip)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
```

**Error message:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at myapp.MenuFragment.onViewCreated(MenuFragment.kt:58)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1823)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1760)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:547)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Show me error for this line :

```
mealChipGroup.findViewById<Chip>(3).isChecked = true
```

I know this error for **NullPointerException**, but my question is why in first time everything is ok. But when close and open dialog show me this error?!! 
How can I fix it?

Comment: You are dynamically creating chips but without setting up an `id`, and you are trying to access a `Chip` via an id `3` which doesn't exist, hence the NPE. Use `setId` on your created `Chip` and use that id to access the view.

Comment: @DarShan Thanks my friend, but how can I set dynamically ID for chip? My list is String, how can I get ID for set in chip? please help me, thanks <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posting as an Answer along with the comment I've added.**

You are dynamically creating Chips but without setting up an id, and you are trying to access a Chip via an id 3 which doesn't exist, hence the `NullPointerException`.

Use `setId` on your created `Chip` and use that to access the view.

Example:

```kotlin
// 1.  Create a variable with a default value of '1' so that we can move sequentially for each Chip's id.
var chipId = 1

// 2. Set 'Id' to your programmatically created Chip.
private fun setupChip(list: MutableList<String>, view: ChipGroup) {
    list.forEach {
        val chip = Chip(requireContext())
        chip.text = it
        chip.id = counter++ // <<<< this
        view.addView(chip)
    }
}

// 3. Now you can access the "third" Chip like before
mealChipGroup.findViewById<Chip>(3).isChecked = true
```

Comment: yeeees, thaaaanks my friend